# Live lock on Linux UNIX socket, what to do?

Tags: linux-kernel, ipc, unix-socket

We operate an Linux application that forks a large number (more than 1000) of child processes. These child processes communicate with master process over UNIX datagram socket (one shared among all child processes). The UNIX datagram socket is used besides other communications also for logging. The whole system works fine until the app has to react to a massive external error - let's say a crash of application database. We observed that in such a situation, child processes start to generate a huge amount of error log events, which is probably correct since each child is impacted by that crash. After few minutes, the load increases above 8000 with 80-100% CPU **system** (not user!) consumption. The state is recoverable only if the app is killed or more commonly, the box becomes unusable due to slow responses and has to be rebooted.

The investigation of core dumps shows that child processes are blocked in `send()` syscall on the UNIX socket, speaking to master process. The UNIX socket is configured as a non-blocking and the app implement proper handling of `EAGAIN`. More in-depth analysis indicates that there is a live lock condition in the kernel. Obviously, processes are competing for access to some resource related to UNIX socket.

Questions: Did you ever meet this or similar behavior before? Do we miss anything about UNIX socket parallelism?

Versions:
 - CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 (Core).
 - Kernel Linux 3.10.0-514.16.1.el7.x86_64 x86_64.

Comment: I wouldn't say that they are "blocked" in send(), only that they are spending most of their process time there. Is it possible that the socket buffer is full? Anyway, thinking about a bug in the kernel would be the very last resort for me.

Comment: Socket buffer is the most certainly full but it is normally handled via EAGAIN mechanism b/c UNIX socket is non-blocking. I agree with the kernel bug part.

Comment: If there is no delay (e.g. sleep) between unsuccessful sends, this is the result you will get.

Answer (score 0):

There is clearly room for improvement on the kernel side here and chances are it's a reasonably low hanging fruit. I'm not going to speculate. Chances are the problem will be easily visible with flamegraphs.

However, considerations of the sort in this context are a red herring. For the sake of argument let's assume the kernel pushes all these error messages with 0 overhead. You have generated gigabytes of repetitive error messages adding no value.

Instead, when there is a major event just log it *once* and then log again that it is cleared (e.g. note the connection to the database died, note when it got back up, but don't log on each query that it is dead). Alternatively you can log this periodically or with ratelimit. Either way, just spamming is the wrong thing to do.

The sheer number of children (1000+?) seems extremely excessive and puts a question mark on the validity of the design of this project. Can you elaborate what's happening there?

Comment: Let's start from the end: I completely agree that the design with huge number of the child processes is at least extravagant. The original purpose of the decision originates at security: each child handles a peer connection encrypted by unique set of keys and intention was to keep that separated on the system/process level. The performance side is also quite impressive, it handles easily +10k concurrent connections, 250 transactions per second with 1-5% of the CPU and less than 0.1 system load. But I'm not here to defend that, next generation will likely switch to "process per CPU core" model.

Comment: Re major event and 'managed' logging: yes, that's a good observation. However, it is not solving the root issue here. There can be other way how to trigger extensive logging and therefore invoke a stall of the app.

Comment: Re "gigabytes of repetitive error messages adding no value" - there is a huge audit log generated from this app that is fed into a powerful log analyzer. These errors are drop in the ocean from that perspective. Similar situations (when not stalling the app) causes a 'nice' peak in a monitoring charts so the operator responds quickly. But again, I don't defend that - it is a clear space for improvement, maybe single but more severe log message will do.

Comment: And finally - re kernel bug: I corrected a text above, it is probably too bold statement. The better statement would be that there is  a way how to exploit live locking in the UNIX socket subsystem so that malicious non-priviledged user can perform local DDoS attack on the system. Because that's exactly what we observe. That's probably not a big deal.

Comment: If you have a legitimate reason to push *lots* of data, you likely should not be doing it over a unix socket. You possibly want to just make everyone write directly to a log file or if it has to go through the main deamon, do it through shared memory. That said, I think at this point you should benchmark how much you can push depending on the number of concurrent clients and see if sensible messages you may have fit the limit.

Comment: Well it is a way to generate excessive load, but one of plenty. Unless it generates soft or hard lockups, there is no fundamental problem - if they cause trouble, you can kill them off. That said, I noted earlier this probably can get significantly faster, but for the purpose of this problem it likely is irrelevant.

Comment: Now that I wrote the previous message, here is an obvious idea: what about trying out separate unix sockets per child? There is no problem polling them with epoll and if indeed lock contention is the culprit, it will be automagically solved.

Comment: Funny enough - we tried to do similar change few weeks ago. Not unix socket per child because we wanted to be nice to master process poll() but let say 100 childs per unix socket. It reduced a incident rate significantly but not completely.

Comment: There should be no problem with 1k fds to be monitored with *epoll* (not poll).

Comment: True, we will try that concept. Thanks.